# How abstract states work in Ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

How abstract states work?
What is the purpose of the abstract tabs?
What is the purpose of the template included in abstract tab?
Can I have more than one abstract states?
Can I switch from one state to another which are in different abstract states?

I modified the app.js to have 2 abstract states from the default tab template.
https://gist.github.com/ashoksahoo/6bcad2c62e1abaa3de74

But I cant get `index.html#/friend/:id working`, and `FriendDetailCtrl` is also not firing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abstract states cannot be navigated to. Their purpose is to have several (non-abstract) states share a common parent, without having to define a parent state that can be navigated to.

This can be useful in many situations. See here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#abstract-states

You can have many abstract states. You can use $state.go() to switch between any two states, even if they have different parents, abstract or not.

Your URL `index.html#/friend/:id` looks strange. tab.triends has an argument. friend does not.

The proper URL for the friends state is: `/#/tab/friends/1234`

For the friend state (no argument!): `/#/friend`

Comment: Yes `/#/tab/friends/` works then `/#/friend` is supposed to be an abstract state, and `/#/friend/1234` should be a friend state instead of being a child state of tab.

Comment: /#/friend/1234 is not a state. /#/friend/ is the state, the number is just a parameter to the state. And the way you have declared the state, it does not take any parameters.

Comment: Is it possible to have a abstract state inside a abstract state ?

Comment: @shruti, yes it is... You might want to have something like this. /friend/home/shruti but really there is no such state like /friend and /friend/home you can create abstract views of /friend and /home and then have /shruti as their parent. Though it's a little late hope it helps someone.